# Sequelize OR Condtion

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to do, Where Student Name Or Email

```
"SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Name='Doe' OR Email='doe@mail.com' "
```

couldn't make OR condtion in Sequelize.

Comment: Can you post your function's code?

Answer (score 2):

you can make OR condition in sequelize like this.

you need to require op method first.

import { Op } from "sequelize";

and then you can pass this condition in findAll or findOne in any sequelize method.

```
where: {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              Name: "Doe",
            }, {
              Email: "doe@mail.com"
            },
          ],
        }
```